# Syntax error while coding on mu with microbit

Tags: syntax-error, bbc-microbit, mu

Here is the code i used to create an Edice for microbit:
from microbit import *
import random
image1 = Image("00000:"
             "00000:"
             "00900:"
             "00000:"
             "00000")
image2 = Image("90000:"
             "00000:"
             "00000:"
             "00000:"
             "00009")
image3 = Image("90000:"
             "00000:"
             "00900:"
             "00000:"
             "00009")
image4 = Image("90009:"
             "00000:"
             "00000:"
             "00000:"
             "90009")
image5 = Image("90009:"
             "00000:"
             "00900:"
             "00000:"
             "90009")
image6 = Image("90009:"
             "00000:"
             "90009:"
             "00000:"
             "90009")
images=[image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6]

while True:
    if button_a.is_pressed():
        for i in range(0, 16):

```
        display.show(images)
        display.show(random.randint.(1, 6))
        sleep(20)
        display.clear
    display.show(image(random.randint(1, 6)))
```

display.show(random.randint.(1, 6)) seems to be registered as a synatax error.
May I know what is the problem and how i can improve on the code

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `.`

You wrote:       `display.show(random.randint.(1, 6))`
It should be:    `display.show(random.randint(1, 6))`